# A series with zeroes of Bessel functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions, bessel-functions

Consider a finite sum
$$
S_n(t)=\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{J_\nu(z_{m,\nu} t)}{J_{\nu+1}(z_{m,\nu})}, \nu>0, 0\leq t <1,
$$
$z_{m,\nu}$ are ordered real positive zeroes of the Bessel function $J_\nu(t)$.
Find good estimates for the sum function $S_n(t)$ which will be enough to prove, that the next series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{S_n(t)}{(z_{n,\nu})^2}
$$
is convergent.

Comment: Is it supposed to be $z_{n,\nu}$ in the last expression?

Comment: Yes, of course, thank you and sorry.